# How do I set the backgroundImage using chrome.runtime.getURL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my content script, I'm trying to inject an `a` tag on the page and set its `backgroundImage`.

```
const newButton = document.createElement('a');
newButton.href = `https://example.com`;
newButton.className = _class
const img_url = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/favicon.png")
console.log('img', img_url) // gives me a valid path
newButton.style.backgroundImage = `url("${img_url}")`; / throws an error
```

However, this throws the error

> exampleSite:973          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Clicking the logged url in the console opens up the image I'm trying to load.

Thanks

**Edit** My `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Example Chrome Extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Adds buttons to certain sites",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://google.com/*",
        "https://yahoo.com"
      ],
      "js": ["bundle.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think posting the manifest.json will give you the answer.

Comment: Added manifest for ya

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `favicon.png` in manifest.json file

```
{
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["images/favicon.png"],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
]
}
```